# Windows10にVisual studio2015をインストールできない

Tags: windows, visual-studio

Windows10(20H2)にVisual Studio 2015をインストールしようとすると
下のようなエラーになってしまいます
パッケージは見つからないし、インターネットからパッケージをダウンロードするにしても結局同じ画面で延々と「次へ」を繰り返すだけになってしまいます
現在のWindows10にVS2015を正常にインストールするには何が足りないのでしょうか

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ありきたりですがインストーラーを「管理者として実行」していないとか？ [Windows 10 で Visual Studio 2015 のインストール手順](http://aqurex.jp/windows-10-%E3%81%A7-visual-studio-2015-%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E6%89%8B%E9%A0%86/) あるいはこちらかも。[【2021年版】VisualStudio 2015のインストールでエラーが出る場合の対処](https://ameblo.jp/mizuhokuzuhara/entry-12660286277.html), [...その２](https://ameblo.jp/mizuhokuzuhara/entry-12660310262.html), [visual studio 2015のインストーラがスプラッシュ表示で止まる(エラーは出ない)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ja-JP/deecce5b-b9fb-42e7-93a5-6a5303ad6f4d/)

Comment: 外していたらすみません、貼り付けていただいている画像に「更新プログラム」と表示されているのが気になるのですが、サービスパック等のアップデート用のパッケージを使用されているということはないでしょうか。VS2015だったらCommunityエディションをダウンロードして試されてみる、という選択肢もありますね。

Comment: インストール系の質問の場合は手順を具体的に示していただけるとより回答が付きやすいと思います。どのサイトを参考にして、どのサイトのどのインストーラをつかって、どこにインストールしようとしてどの手順で失敗しているのか。期待する動作は何か。この辺りを詳細に質問に追記してみてください

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSDNのサイトからダウンロードする際に
64ビット版をダウンロードすると失敗するのですが
32ビット版をダウンロードしたらインストールできました
どちらもファイル名はx86と64に対応してるようなファイル名ですがバージョンが微妙に違うのでそのせいかも

Comment: OS 自体は 32bit と 64bit のどちらだったのでしょうか？

Comment: 64ビットです。